# using twilio to send text picture image

Tags: php, curl, sms, twilio, mms

I'm trying to send an image via text using twilio using php and curl.
sending text is fine...works great.
I'm trying to add in an image as well - seems to be ignoring the image related fields (no error - just no image).

Below is the code I'm using.

```
function send_sms( $sid, $token, $to, $from, $body ) {

  $uri = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' . $sid . '/SMS/Messages';
  $auth = $sid . ':' . $token;

  $postfields = Array( 
      'From'=>$from,
      'To'=>$to,
      'Body'=>$body,
      'MediaUrl'=>'http://imageurl.jpg',
      'MediaContentType'=>'image/jpeg'
  );



  // start cURL
  $res = curl_init();

  // set cURL options
  curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_URL, $uri );
  curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields );
  curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth ); 
  curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

  // send cURL
  $result = curl_exec( $res );
  return $result;
}
```

Update: Issue Solved: The problem was I was using the wrong API URL!
I needed to eliminate the "/SMS" - which in itself works but only for
text only messages. Once I used just $sid.'/Messages' - it worked fine.

Also, /Messages will return XML status. If you use /Messsages.json it
will return a JSON block.

Comment: Is your `http://imageurl.jpg` accessible over the web? Twilio will need to be able to retrieve it

Comment: yes, the image url is accessible. Initially the image was a .php program that sends an image - which works fine. However, to be sure it wasn't that - I changed it to an actual .jpg image. it is also under 1MB in size.

Comment: Solved: I needed to use the API URL of: $uri = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' . $sid . '/Messages'; (removed the /SMS).

Answer (score -1):

According to their API documentation:

`The URL of the media you wish to send out with the message. gif , png and jpeg content is currently supported and will be formatted correctly on the recipient's device. Other types are also accepted by the API. The media size limit is 5MB. If you wish to send more than one image in the message body, please provide multiple MediaUrls values in the POST request. You may include up to 10 MediaUrls per message.`

You specify a .jpg and not a .jpEg.  Could be the issue.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

Comment: Also check your permissions on the image and make sure you can view it in the browser.

Comment: No, file ending and file types don't always exactly match. Please don't post answers which are not actually answers but are questions.